# Create an arrow on the block element an save this with canvas

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas

I need to draw an arrow indicating the route to the dynamic chess board, this means that the board should not lose the property of movement on her chess.
I do this as follows:

```css
.arrow{
    height: 5px;
    width: 40px;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    top: 100px;
    left: 100px;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-50deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-50deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(-50deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-50deg);
    transform: rotate(-50deg);
    cursor: pointer;}
#arrowHead{
    width: 5px !important;
    height: 3px;
    font-size: 10px;
    font-weight: 800;
    float: left; 
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    color: green;}
#arrowBody{
    width: 33px;
    height: 3px;
    margin-top: 1px;
    background-color: green;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    top: 2.5px;
    left: 2px;}
```

```html
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="arrow">
    <div id="arrowBody"></div>
    <div id="arrowHead" class="glyphicon glyphicon-play"></div>
</div>
```

I keep it in a pattern as follows:

```js
$('#saveImage').on('click',function(){
    html2canvas($('.game'), {
        onrendered: function (canvas) {
            var newCanvas = document.createElement("canvas");
            newCanvas.setAttribute('width',700);
            newCanvas.setAttribute('height',700);
            var ctx = newCanvas.getContext('2d');
            ctx.drawImage(canvas,0,0,canvas.width, canvas.height,0,0,700,700);
            var dataURL = newCanvas.toDataURL();
            var img = $(document.createElement('img'));
            img.attr('src', dataURL);
            $('#download').attr('href', newCanvas.toDataURL("image/png"));
            $('#download').attr('download','new file.png');
            $('#download')[0].click();
        }
    });
});
```

The result is a picture:
[image]

But I want to get this:
[image]

Prompt me please what I'm doing wrong or how I can get around this problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try setting `.arrow`'s position attribute to `absolute`. What happens then?

Comment: The same result and with position:absolute;

Comment: I learned that html2canvas library does not support CSS transforms property, someone who knows how to get around this problem?

Comment: You should draw all the shapes in your canvas in the onrendered function as shown here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial/Drawing_shapes. I also don't understand why do you need to create another canvas just for the 'toDataUrl', you could reuse the one that provides html2canvas

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood how the "html2sanvas" works. At the moment I'm using this library only at the stage when I need to save the final layout of the elements on the board. It's only at this stage, the library creates a "canvas" and on it draws my board, then saves everything as an image. So, for drawing arrows, I need a permanent canvas on which I can also draw the chess icons themselves, but they must retain all their functions.

Comment: I have insufficient experience to create such structures. At the current stage, I abandoned the idea of ​​drawing arrows. But if you have an example that will solve my problem, I will be very grateful to you.